# Java code Char and Int

Tags: java

I want to print out only 
Int from String and first 2 char from string as well so, how i can do that, please help me thank!!

suppose,

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class match1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String address = "1234 main street";
    }
}
```

Output should be like:

> 1234 ma

How can i do that please help me!! Thanks!!

Comment: You need to provide some more detail here. Will all Strings start with 4 numbers? Will all start with a number? Will there ever be a String like 123abc (without a space)? Also, what code have you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Would you mind doing some of my homework if I do some of yours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String address = "1234 main street";
String[] tokens = address.split(" ");
System.out.println(tokens[0]+" "+tokens[1].substring(0,2));
```

Comment: thank you sir, Is there any way that i can do this print number 1234 its done so is there any way that i can print street name without street like "main"?? please help me thanks!!

Comment: Your question is not clear, sorry...

Comment: nooo, nevermind, i get it, thanks, for your help!!